# Calling Parent Constructor on Subclass instance

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor

If I remember correctly, in C++ it is possible to call a parent's class's constructor on a subclass's instance, so that an instance of the parent class will be created so that only the overlapping attributes will be copied over. Does such a functionality exist in python such that the following 'python' code would do the same?

If I have a parent class Fruit

```
class Fruit():
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

and a child class Apple

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, color, seeds):
        self.seeds = seeds
        super().__init__(color)
```

You could do

```
an_apple = Apple('red', 42)
a_fruit = Fruit(an_apple)
```

and get a red fruit.

Comment: In C++ the parent constructor is called first... automatically.

Comment: Your first two code blocks seem to be exactly what you want. The third block makes no sense! I suspect you are thinking of a copy constructor of the base class.

Comment: I don't know what your c++ snippet is trying to do, but I suspect it won't achieve what you want.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sorry about that, I've removed the tag and clarified a bit

Comment: @quamrana that's exactly my question! :) Is there such a functionality that would actually make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The only think I can think of is to make a Factory Method:

```
class Fruit():
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    @staticmethod
    def MakeFruit(aFruit):
        return Fruit(aFruit.color)
```

usage:

```
an_apple = Apple('red', 42)  #assuming Apple as before
a_fruit = Fruit('blue')
a_red_fruit = Fruit.MakeFruit(an_apple)
```